# Selector method does not call

Tags: ios, swift3, selector

I have simply `UIViewController` class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var _ = Test(parentView: view)
    }
}
```

and another class:

```
import UIKit

class Test: NSObject {

    let parentView: UIView

    init(parentView: UIView) {
        self.parentView = parentView

        super.init()

        addButton()
    }
}

extension Test {

    func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        parentView.addSubview(button)
    }

    func tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tap")
    }
}
```

`Test` class inherits `NSObject` because without it I get compilator massage `Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'tap(sender:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C`.

The problem is that method `tap(sender: UIButton)` does not call. I don't know why.

(Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1, appTarget: iOS 9.0)

#### Edit 1

I edited implementation of `Test` class according @vadian suggestions but it still does not work.

#### Edit 2

When I move `Test` class implementation to `ViewController` everything works but I don't want to do this. Why this not work in separate class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have test your project the problem is in this line `var _ = Test(parentView: view)`, where you are creating object of your custom class `Test`. So after th `viewDidLoad` its instance is loss or deinit. Thats the reason you are not getting action call with button.

To solve the issue declare one instance property of type `Test` inside your `ViewController` class and initialize this property in `viewDidLoad`. Now it will call action when you tap on button.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var test: Test?       

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.test = Test(parentView: view)
    }
}
```

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz Welcome mate :)